# Is there a way to export collection in a Firestore database to a json or csv file?

Tags: json, firebase, csv, google-cloud-firestore

I have looked at the import/export documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import but this way only seems to export for use in other databases, and use in BigQuery, but if I want to use the data in say, Excel, I would need a csv file for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into the Firestore UI or API for exporting to a CSV or Excel, but you can of course use the API to read the data and write the CSV/XLS file yourself.

There are also some promising links in the results of searching for [firestore export to csv](https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+export+to+csv), like this tutorial on [Exporting Firestore Collection as CSV into Cloud Storage on Demand, the easy way](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exporting-firestore-collection-csv-into-cloud-storage-on-demand-the-easy-way-4a4a08c664ab) and this tutorial on [CSV Exports from Firestore](https://fireship.io/lessons/csv-exports-from-firestore-database-with-cloud-functions/)